# Detect changes in multiple TextBox compared to a the initial data of DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, textbox

I have a form with multiple `TextBox` controls and I want to check if any value were changed since form opened.

I am showing a single record of the `DataTable` using some `TextBox` controls and since there are multiple fields, so there are multiple `TextBox` controls on my form.I am using data-binding. and I want to highlight `TextBox` controls if their value is different than original value of row at load time.

Here is what I've tried. I used a `DataTable` and filled it by data represent as single row and 5 columns from a stored procedure in database .In `Validated` event in the `TextBox` the code compare the value between the suitable column in `DataTable` and the editing text. if it changed the `TextBox.Backcolor` turned to yellow. Here is my code :

```
private void txtName_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = Person.DETECT_CHANGES(txtName.Text, txtNickName.Text); //could be many columns here

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        if ((txtName.Text).Trim() != row["fullName"].ToString())
        {
            txtName.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            break;further
        }
        else
        {
            txtName.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
```

It works fine. But since I have many `TextBoxe` so I want a method to compare every `TextBox` by its column in the `DataTable` without repeated the code for every control one by one. for example if text of `txtName` (the `TextBox`) compared to the first column in the `DataTable` called `fullName` and the textbox `txtNickName` compared by the second column called `nickname` ..... etc and give me the result (turned any changed `TextBox.BackColor` to yellow).

Comment: Why do you have a `foreach` loop while you want to check if the `TextBox` value has been changed? It's a single value and should be compared with a single value.

Comment: Thats right .. but i did that because i was planed to compare many textboxes with many columns .. as i want in my question

Comment: Just to make sure about your requirement  **1)** You are showing a single record of the DataTable using some TextBoxes?  **2)** You are using data-binding. **3)** You want to highlight Textboxes if their value is different than original value of row at load time.

Comment: The datatable has many columns say 5 columns take its data from a database .. and i have 5 textboxes and i want to highlight any textbox that its value different than its column in the datatable

Comment: Just a single `DataRow`?

Comment: yes .. in the datatable single row and more than one column ..

Answer (score 2):

Just get the TextBox instance from all the validated events by typecasting sender object and pass that textbox as a argument to common function as below

```
private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox t = (TextBox)sender;
    Common_Validated(t,e);

}

private void Common_Validated(TextBox txtName, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = Person.DETECT_CHANGES(txtName.Text);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        if ((txtName.Text).Trim() != row["fullName"].ToString())
        {
            txtName.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            txtName.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sooo sorry .. i made a mistake ... the datatable has more than one column .. so i want to compare every textbox by its column in datatable ... sorry again

Comment: you can access the datatable row attach to current textbox row.. which is bound to datatable and perform logic based on the value in common handler

Comment: There is no point in having 2 method. Just keep a single `private void Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)` method and handle all validated events using this handler. `Sender` points to the `TextBox` that raised the event.

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().ForEach(c => c.BackColor = Color.White);
    Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(c => c.Text.Trim() != row["fullName"].ToString())
                .ToList().ForEach(c=> c.BackColor = Color.Yellow);        
}
```

Or use `row[c.Name]` instead of `row["fullName"]` if the `TextBox`'s name and column's name are same.
Or if they're not same you can also use the index of the column like this `row[0]` instead of `row["fullName"]` if you want to compare with column 1 or `row[1]` if you want to compare with column 2 and so on.

Comment: the TextBox's name and column's name are not the same.

Comment: @a_fathy So what is the column's name that you want to compare it with `TextBox.Text`?

Comment: @a_fathy You can also use the index of the column like this `row[0]` if you want to compare with column 1 and `row[1]` if you want to compare with column 2 and so on...

Comment: i edit me question to clear what i want .. sorry for disturbance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are binding multiple textboxes to a single `DataRow` object in a `DataTable`.

Each Item in a DataRow can be queried to obtain its original value like so:

`var origval = theRow.Item[columnIndex, DataRowVersion.Current];`, that is until you call `AcceptChanges` or `EndEdit`, at which point the proposed value becomes current.

So, your `DETECT_CHANGE` method should compare the `DataRowVersion.Current` and `DataRowVersion.Proposed`.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: MSDN link: [DataRowVersion documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowversion(v=vs.110).aspx)